# How to filter and replace words in JS from an array

Tags: javascript

**Hello everyone!**

I have a chat application.
When i click send button it first checks the message if it has any badwords that are in the bad words Array.

lets say that duck is a bad word.

When i type duck it detects it and blocks it but if i do dUck or DUCK it doesn't detect it.

How can i fix this.

This is my code

```
 const arrayBad = bannedwords.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < arrayBad; i++) {
            if (bannedwords[i].toLowerCase() == name || bannedwords[i].toUpperCase() == name) {
                message = message.replace(new RegExp(bannedwords[i], "g"), "****");
                if(browserName == "Safari"){
                    Swal.fire("Your message has been blocked for using bad words. Please remove them.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayBad; i++) {
            if (name.includes(bannedwords[i].toLowerCase()) || bannedwords[i].toUpperCase() == name) {
                message = message.replace(new RegExp(bannedwords[i], "g"), "****");
                if(browserName == "Safari"){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered `bannedwords[i].toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: you can use try catch error handling blocks . like first try when user clicks on send button then the whole msg converted to upper case ,lowercase as well and your whole array datas are also must in the same case(lower/upper) . if no match will be found then try block will be executed and msg will be sent successfully otherwise catch block will run and find the bad words among the msg .

Comment: I can't do that since i still want to send message but replace their bad word with *** stars

Comment: I wonder why you show the error message only when `browserName` variable is `Safari` (`browserName == "Safari"`). Seems very strange to me!

Comment: The regex does not work on safari for some weird reason.

Answer (score 0):

just one suggestion you don't need to check lowercase and uppercase.
Just for checking purposes, you can bring both to either lowercase or uppercase.

const arrayBad = bannedwords.length;

```
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayBad; i++) {
            if (bannedwords[i].toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()) {
                message = message.replace(new RegExp(bannedwords[i], "g"), "****");
                if(browserName == "Safari"){
                    Swal.fire("Your message has been blocked for using bad words. Please remove them.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayBad; i++) {
            if (name.toLowecase().includes(bannedwords[i].toLowerCase())) {
                message = message.replace(new RegExp(bannedwords[i], "g"), "****");
                if(browserName == "Safari"){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

plus if you want to replace the word you can get the index of the bad word in the message and replace it, but what I understood from the question is you want to block the entire massage instead.

if you want to replace it one way to do it is. you can enhance the logic.

```
int start = message.toLowerCase().indexOf(bannedWords[i])
message = message.slice(0,start) + message.slice(start+bannedWords[i].length, message.length)
```